# How to give neon effect to Scene Builder object?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I wonder if we can give a neon effect like the following example on Autodesk Forge. ?

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Simple-Glow.html

Comment: AFAIK, Forge Viewer doesn't support `THREE.Sprite` at this moment. It uses a self-managed `three.js` r71. Not all features are included. Could you share more details on why you want to use this and how important to you?

Comment: I want to make an object blink as an alert notification. Or change color object Scene Builder, is there a blog about this?

Comment: maybe this one: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-threejs-shape-simulate-alertor